# How can I properly bind and fill Kendo UI grid with two table EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, kendo-grid

My project has two main issues that prevent me from being able to do a normal, basic Kendo UI gridbind. 1. I do not have full access to the required SQL data (I cannot create a view) 2. One of the fields is incredibly large (the field overloads a ViewModel).

I was able to get my grid to work, but I feel that there is a better way to accomplish the task. My problem, essentially, is that I can only seem to gridbind to a single table of DB. To get passed this, I bound to the foreign key field and used a clientTemplate to fill the data from the read, but I feel like there should be a more direct way to be able to bind the field to the data. My read data is an actionresult Linq join from EF, converted to JSON.
Here is my code, if anyone can make a suggestion. D_Type from table 2 is what I am trying to bind directly to the column:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProjectName.Models.Table1>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Scrollable()
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Bound(c => c.P_Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.E_Name);
        //Cannot be directly bound to a column because it is part of Table2 table
        columns.Bound(c => c.TypeId).Title("Type").ClientTemplate("#= D_Type #").Filterable(false);            
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Details").Click("showDetails")).Title("Results").Width(80);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Destination);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Location);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Version);
        columns.Bound(c => c.StartDt);
        columns.Bound(c => c.EndDt);
        columns.Bound(c => c.StartDt).Title("Duration").ClientTemplate("#: calcDuration(StartDt, EndDt) #").Sortable(false).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.);
        columns.Bound(c => c.MiscNotes).ClientTemplate("#: errorDisplay(ResultObject) # ").Sortable(false).Filterable(false);


    })
    //Style dictates full grid height
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 725px;" })
    .Filterable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Sortable(sortable => sortable
        .AllowUnsort(true)
        .SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(false)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("StartDt").Descending())
        .Read(read => read.Action("Project_Read", "Grid"))
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(true)
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bind your grid to ProjectName.Models.Table1.

Instead, bind it to a ViewModel that contains the fields from Table1 and the field from Table2 that you want to display in the Grid, i.e.

```
public class SpecificGridViewModel
{
    public string P_Name { get; set; }
    // Other fields you want from Table1
    // ...
    // PLUS the field(s) you want from the other, joined table.
    public string D_Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have your Project_Read method return a list of these ViewModels that you have constructed from your LINQ query instead of a list of Table1s.

i.e. write a LINQ query that returns the exact data you want(data from Table1 joined with Table2.D_Type via Table1.TypeID) and return a result set of custom ViewModel that you create to hold the data from the query and then bind your grid to that model instead of the "raw" Table1 model.

Comment: This works 99% of the time, but unfortunately I am getting System.OutofMemory error doing it this way because of the size of one of the fields.

Comment: Then continue doing it the way you doing it(with fetching and showing D_Type on-demand)...there's not much that the grid can do to help if the size of one of your fields is so large.  I also question the need to display data like that(not yours in particular, I also question a customers need for a 1200 page report that they will never read and really just want an XLSX dump)...if a computer can't process it comfortably, is human really going to process/do anything meaningful with the data on screen or will their eyes glaze over?

Comment: Re-reading your solution allowed me to see where my error was. I had placed the ViewModel in the ActionResult Read, and not as a separate Model. This was why it was sending too much data to the VM. Sometimes you just need to take a step back and read things again. Thank you.